# Query a table to find records with given text

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have below 3 records in my table(**TAG_DATA**) column(**TAGS**).

```
car,bus,van
bus,car,ship,van
ship
```

I wrote a query to get records which has `car` and `bus` as below.

```
SELECT * FROM TAG_DATA
  where TAGS like '%car, bus%'
```

But above query return only below record.

```
car,bus,van
```

But i need to get output as below. because both records have `car` and `bus`

```
car,bus,van
bus,car,ship,van
```

How can i write a query for this ? I'm using MS SQL Server.

**UPDATED**

I'm selecting tags from multi select combobox in my application. so i need to give text in that. so can't use `and`/ `or` in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(MAX)='car, bus'

SELECT DISTINCT B.*
FROM(
    SELECT 
         LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS CVS  
    FROM  
    (
         SELECT
            CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@input, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS  
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) 
)x  INNER JOIN TAG_DATA b on TAGS like '%'+CVS+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use this. because i'm selecting tags from multi select combobox in my application. so i need to give text in that. so can't use `and` or `or`.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, I guess this is your requirement.

Comment: Is there an any method to achieve this with out creating a new table ?

Comment: Please check my other try.

Comment: I need to filter result from `TAG_ID`. so how should i use `where` clause in above query ? can i use it as `INNER JOIN TAG_DATA b on TAGS like '%'+CVS+'%' where TAG_ID = 101` ?

Comment: @Bishan Yes, you can use a where condition after the like condition.

Answer (score 2):

Here, only records having `car, bus` tags in sequence will be fetched.

For the desired result, below query is beneficial :

```
SELECT * FROM TAG_DATA
where TAGS like '%car, bus%' or  TAGS like '%bus, car%'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55ad4f/1)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use this. because i'm selecting tags from multi select combobox in my application. so i need to give text in that. so can't use `and`.

Comment: Sorry. also can't use `OR`.

Comment: @Luv What do you mean by `Complete query` ?

Comment: @Bishan I think it u can use a `reverse function` in your application or in your `Query` to achieve your desired Result.

Comment: Or you could do it like this: `SELECT * FROM Table1
where TAGS like '%car%' and  TAGS like '%bus%'` and then it will work even if bus and car aren't consecutive

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TAG_DATA
  where TAGS like '%car,%' and TAGS like  '%bus,%'
```

I intentionally used the commas. It depends on your data The following query will also work atleast for the example above.

```
SELECT * FROM TAG_DATA
  where TAGS like '%car,%' and TAGS like  '%bus,%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use this. because i'm selecting tags from multi select combobox in my application. so i need to give text in that. so can't use `and`.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
SELECT * FROM TAG_DATA
      where TAGS like '%[BUS,CAR],[CAR,BUS]%'
```